# Is it possible to do "Class<? extends foo> foo"?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I'm having an hirarchy like this:

```
class Foo {
...
}
class Bar extends Foo {
...
}
class Baz extends Foo {
...
}
```

And now I'm trying to declare an object like this in class foo:

```
Class<? extends Foo> anyName;
```

Then there is some method where I want to do this:

```
anyName = new Foo();
```

But it won't let me do that. Can anyone help me out?

I've already read several guides/tutorials/documents on generics and wildcards. But I haven't fount quite the solution to this problem.

EDIT: Fixed the capitalization. Sorry that was a typing error. My original classes are indeed like that.

EDIT2: The goal here is to get a singleton-instance of Foo.

EDIT3: I'm really sorry, NOW it should be correct! Shame on me :/

Comment: `Class` is not the reserved word to declare a new type. Use `class` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not check if my capitalization is correct :/ now it should be more clear.

Comment: If you think `Class<? extends Foo>` represents an *instance* of `Foo` (or some subtype), you're mistaken. It represents the runtime *class* of some subtype of `Foo`. All you need in your example is the type `Foo` itself.

Answer (score 3):

A `Class<Foo>` is not type compatible with a `Foo`.

```
Class<Foo> c = new Foo();
```

... won't work for that reason.

If you want an object of type `Class`, the normal way to do it is to use the class name followed by `.class`:

```
Class<Foo> c = Foo.class
```

You can make this handle subclasses like this:

```
Class<? extends Foo> c = Bar.class;
```

However, you probably wouldn't be asking this question if you knew classes well enough to have a reason to have a variable of that type. Normally we want an *instance* of `Foo` or `Bar`:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Bar b = new Bar();
Foo c = new Bar(); // type compatible because of inheritance
```

---

You mention that you want to call a method and/or cast your variable.

You can do:

```
Foo a = ...;
if(a instanceof Bar) {
    Bar b = (Bar) a;
    b.someMethodOfBar();
}
```

However, both casting and `instanceof` are "code smells" -- not necessarily wrong, but evidence that something could be designed better.

It would be better if your method was declared in `Foo`, perhaps as an abstract method, and overriden in `Bar` and `Baz`.

```
 Foo a = ...;
 a.someMethod();   // if it's a Bar, this is Bar.someMethod()
                   // if it's a Baz, this is Baz.someMethod()
```

This is called *polymorphism* and is one of the most important concepts in OO programming.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what you are trying to get from here, but my suggestion is too long for a comment.

What you want to achieve is to get a variable which is an instance of `Foo` so you can do this `anyName = new Foo()`. But you also would like to be able to do this `anyName = new Bar();` or this `anyName = new Baz();`.

If I am right here, you don't need to use generics. Instead, you just have to define `anyName` as follows:

```
Foo anyName;
```

**Update based on the comments**

You can't get an instance of an object you don't know. I would used one of this approaches:

You can just cast your variable to the time you need to. For example:

```
((Bar) anyName).someBarMethod();
```

Alternatively, you can create a generic method for getting the type you need. This is useful when you need some flexibility when you cast:

```
public <T extends Foo> T getFoo(Class<T> type){
    return (T) anyName;
}
```

Comment: This is what I had first, but then the next problem comes into play: 
I want to call an method on anyName, but then I need to cast anyName of either Bar or Baz. And I can't find a way around that.

Comment: @Hann3s Sounds like you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/304954). If you need to call some common method, it should be defined in the common class. If it's not common, then you'll have to keep separate variables or cast to the correct type before calling the method. This is often indicative of a deeper design flaw, but it's hard to help without more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reflection API to create a new instance of whatever `Class<? extends Foo> anyName` is by using `anyName.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

Here is a detailed example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: OP clearly doesn't understand classes or inheritance properly yet -- reflection is not something they need in their life yet.